# Can we use the past tense followed by present tense to describe videos or movies we've seen before?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

For example:This video talks about the importance of giving affection to your pets, they were mentioning how you should make enough time for your pets to ensure their happiness in the long run, it was posted by PetFriends.

I watched the movie "Cradles" yesterday, it was a good movie and it talks about the upbringing of two brothers and the hardships their parents face to give them a decent childhood.

Comment: At least be consistent. Either *it **was** a good movie and it **talked** about [blah blah]* or *it **is** a good movie and it **talks** about...*

Answer (score 0):

Your example is fine. You *watched* (past tense) the movie because that event happened yesterday, but the movie *talks* (present tense) because the movie, as a recording, will continue to talk to others.

This is often the idiomatic way to refer to recorded media, including the printed word. Just consider these quotes from book and record reviews:

- "... the gusto with which he **sings** those final two lines..."
- "On track number 7 he **sings** 'I believe I can fly'"
- "...in his own book he **deals** with a much longer period..."

This is idiomatic because you are not speaking about a past event, but the ongoing effect that the media in question will have on people. Of course, if you're talking about the event of making a movie, writing a book, recording a song, then you use the past tense:

- he sang in the studio
- he made the movie in Hollywood
- he wrote in his book...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. The protocol I've always understood is that one SHOULD use the present tense to refer to material in a pice, the way Astralbee describes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133370)